# Why Doesn't endObject work?

Tags: game-engine

If **new_piece = scene.addObject(shape)** makes a piece appear, why does **new_piece = scene.endObject(shape)** NOT make the piece disappear?

```
if key[bge.events.PAD5] == pressed:              # If 5 key pressed
    target = scene.objects['Empty1']             # Find where it goes
    new_piece = scene.addObject(shape)           # Create the piece..
    new_piece.worldPosition = target.worldPosition  # and place it.

if key[bge.events.PAD0] == pressed:
    new_piece = scene.endObject(shape)
                # 'KX_Scene' object has no attribute 'endObject'
```

This is the simplest game I could make to figure this out. The entire blend file is here:
https://github.com/quazipseudo/Done-Gone/blob/master/ApDisap002.blend?raw=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process of ending an object is different to the process of creating it. Typically you delete it using a reference to the object, using the function `piece.endObject()`

Modifying your above code:

```
if key[bge.events.PAD5] == pressed:              # If 5 key pressed
    target = scene.objects['Empty1']             # Find where it goes
    new_piece = scene.addObject(shape)           # Create the piece..
    new_piece.worldPosition = target.worldPosition  # and place it.

if key[bge.events.PAD0] == pressed:
    # First up we retrieve the existing object. In this case we get it by name.
    # Make sure the name is the name of the object you want to remove
    existing_object = scene.objects.get(shape)
    # If it exists, then remove it
    if existing_object is not None:
        existing_object.endObject()
```

Comment: Yes! **existing_object = scene.objects.get('Ball')**, I replaced 'existing_object' with just 'x'  to see if it was a random variable or something bge would always recognize, and that worked too. So you could use any variable name. It surprises me that setting a variable to an instance of an object gives the variable authority over the object. I find it counter intuitive. I would expect changing the obj would reset the var, not the reverse. Following that logic, would this progression be correct? (a = 'Dog'), (b = 'Cat'), (new_variable = 'Dog'), (new_variable = 'Cat'), (a = 'Cat')????

Comment: There are two separate things: using an object and operating on an object. If you have a=3, and then do a+5,you don't expect the variable 'a' to change. This is using the variable 'a'. But if you have a car, and paint it blue, then you expect the car to be blue.
So in your cat/dog example, 'a' will remain as dog.